# Change value of form boxes with jQuery onBlur

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, onblur

I'm looking to write a jQuery function that will change the value of other input boxes when an onBlur event occurs.  In the code below, I'm attempting to read in the value of the input box that has been altered and use its value to manipulate the value of the other input boxes.  Eventually, this will be used as a conversion utility.  I feel like I'm pretty close here, can someone help?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#a').bind('blur', function() {
    var a = $('#a').val();

    var b = a*1;
    var c = a*1;

    $('#b').val(b);
    $('#c').val(c);

});

$('#b').bind('blur', function() {
    var b = $('#b').val();

    var a = b*2;
    var c = b*2;

    $('#a').val(b);
    $('#c').val(c);
});

$('#c').bind('blur', function() {
    var c = $('#c').val();

    var a = c*3;
    var b = c*3;

    $('#a').val(a);
    $('#b').val(b);

});
</script>
<div style="width:500px">
    <table width="500">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="a" value="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="b" value="1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="c" value="1"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$('#a').val(b);
```

to

```
$('#a').val(a);
```

in second bind.

Answer (score 0):

i found your error:

change this:

```
$('#b').bind('blur', function() {
    var b = $('#b').val();

    var a = b*2;
    var c = b*2;

    $('#a').val(b);
    $('#c').val(c);
});
```

to this:

```
$('#b').bind('blur', function() {
    var b = $('#b').val();

    var a = b*2;
    var c = b*2;

    $('#a').val(a);
    $('#c').val(c);
});
```

you accidentally gave `$('#a').val = b` when there is no b

see answer working fully here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ru6FV/

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to fire whole javascript after html is loaded correctly:

```
$(function() {
  $('#a').bind(...
  ...
  });
});
```

What exactly is the issue? It seems to work somehow (didn't check for the calculations)... [implementation with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FqZZC/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `</script>` tag after loading jquery.